# jquery .html refresh not working on Chrome

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a page that has a list of tasks that each have a dropdown with a list of teams the task is assignable to, but due to the amount of tasks I can't pre-populate it in the Action as it slows down the pagination/display of the tasks quite significantly.
So instead, on click of the dropdown I have a jquery function that calls an action returning a Json string.

All of that works fine in Firefox, but in Chrome when the user clicks on the dropdown, the call is made, but the dropdown does not populate. The user has to click away and reopen the dropdown which then has the data from the initial call (there is no second call).
The data gets added just fine to the HTML, but the dropdown does not get refreshed.

```
$("#teamsSpanFor1354405").click(function () {
    var issueId = 1354405;
    var ddl = $("#teamsSpanFor1354405").find("select.ddlTeamsAssignTask");

    if (ddl.find("option").length == 1) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '/Tracker/Task/DisplayAssignTaskToTeam',
            data: { milestoneId: 1, issueId: issueId, jsonRequest: "true" },
            type: 'POST',
            async: true,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                var html = "<option value=''>Assign to Team</option>";
                $.each(data, function () {
                    html += "<option value='" + this.Id + "'>" + this.Name + "</option>";
                });
                console.log(html);
                ddl.html(html);
            }
        });
    }
});

@using (Ajax.BeginForm("AssignTaskToTeam", new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "assignTaskForIssue" + Model.IssueId, OnSuccess = "ConfirmAssignment(" + Model.Milestone.Id + ")" }))
{
    <input id="MilestoneId" name="MilestoneId" type="hidden" value="1"/>
    <input id="InspectorIssueId" name="InspectorIssueId" type="hidden" value="1354405"/>
    <span id="teamsSpanFor1354405">
            <select id="TeamId" class="ddlTeamsAssignTask" style="width: 125px; " name="TeamId">
                <option value="">Assign to Team</option>
            </select>
        <input class="btnAssign btnClassDisabled" type="submit" value="Assign" disabled="disabled"/>
    </span>
}
```

Comment: What does the rendered jQuery look like? I'm assuming that the stuff with the `@` signs is the asp.net server-side stuff?

Comment: Yeah this is using an ASP.Net MVC3 web app. I've edited the post a bit as I actually noticed that Firebug is not displaying the HTML but the Chrome Developer tool is showing it just fine. So the issue is Chrome not refreshing the dropdown when new HTML <options> get added to it.

Comment: jQuery (and JavaScript as a whole) works client-side, posting the jQuery that the browser sees might go some way to solving your problem, that way we don't have to infer what the browser *might* see.

Comment: Updated the code to show what one of the task would look like.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `.append` instead of `.html`? like:

```
$.each(data, function() { 
    ddl.append($('<option></option>').val(this.Id).text(this.Name));
});
```

In my opinion they should both work the same, but it might be worth a shot to try changing it since `.html` isn't behaving.

Alternatively, if Chrome just refuses to refresh the dropdown under any circumstances, you might be able to replace the dropdown with a link, then do the ajax call when the user clicks on the link and replace the link element with a newly-constructed dropdown and open it.

Or (perhaps more hackish) you could build in a delay (`setTimeout` during document.ready) to automatically populate the dropdown after the page had loaded regardless of whether the user clicked on it, avoiding the need to refresh the options after the select was already open.

Comment: Actually I did .append first, when that didn't work I went with .html In both cases the html does get added properly to the element, but Chrome won't refresh the dropdown already displayed.

Comment: The link solution might work yeah, but it's not a solution I really like much :/ The delay might be a solution as well, though would I be able to cancel any calls made should the user decide to paginate and therefore not want to load the first pages' dropdown?

Comment: Yes, if you want to cancel the delayed function you can store the return value of `setTimeout` and then pass it to `clearTimeout`, like: `var ival = setTimeout(yourFunc, 3000); clearTimeout(ival);`

Comment: P.S. I agree that both solutions are subpar...bummer that the refresh doesn't work on the fly! Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this:

```
<select id="selTasks">
    <option> loading...</option>
</select>
```

And then, instead of the click event, you bind to the mousedown event, which is invoked *before* the dropdown displays. You could even go so far as to make your ajax call synchronous instead of asynchronous, they might see / feel the pain, but it'd get the job done.

```
$(function() {

    $("#selTasks").mousedown(function () {
        if ($(this).find("option").length === 1) {
          $(this).html("<option>option one</option><option>option two</option>");  
        } 
    });
});
```

Another option is to just use a combobox implementation with something like jquery ui's autocomplete.

That said, one of the big performance trends (I was at a conference were some Google folks even talked about it), is to figure out intent.  So, if they mouseover the dropdown, then start getting the data for it, as it takes something like 200ms for the brain to click, in that time, you could have gotten a fair bit of data.

Answer (score 1):

So when you click on the dropdown you make the call and repopulate a dropdownlist?  Why not bind to the 'onchange' event and then append the  tag like @Matt Winckler describes.  I have used this for several cascading dropdownlists and it works great!!!  Please post if you need further instruction on the coding but I feel confident this will work ;)